# How do I add an overlay effect here?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/lenjerie-sexy/rochii-sexy.html)

On this page,you will find a product list.I want to add at this list an overlay effect.

**CODE HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.altradona.ro/lenjerie-sexy/rochii-sexy/rochie-7033-black.html" title="Rochie 7033 black" class="product-image">
      <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/4/1432654037.png" data-srcx2="http://www.altradona.ro/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/504x504/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/4/1432654037.png" width="252" height="252" alt="Rochie 7033 black">
</a>
```

I should to add this effect to `a` tag
You can inspect the site to see clearer code, this is just a sample.

I tried to use this CSS code but not working:

**CODE CSS:**

```
.regular a:hover{
opacity:0.4;
background:url("http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/OVERLAY.png");
}
```

What is wrong with this code?
Can you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you aren't applying an **overlay** with that code...you're changing the opacity and bg image. An overlay has to be a **separate element (or pseudo-element)**. Where is that in your code?

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2akted5m/?

Comment: That is why I am here because I do not know ... if I knew only post the issue. I needed an example

Comment: @Dmitriy Your example is good but what if you copy the code in my site is not working?
You can do a test?

Comment: example http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qjq456mp/;  add new code  http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bg9fgh39/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how an overlay works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJxeVo

you have to have a `parent element` which has to have a child element position absolute in it.

You could build your html like that :

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="src" alt="tree" />
  <div class="itemOverlay"></div> <!-- OVERLAY -->
</div>
```

Due to the fact that the item with the class itemOverlay is being positioned:absolute it will be above all other elements within that div and create your overlay effekt.

And with the following css the magic  happens :)

```
.item{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.item img{
  width:100%;
}
.itemOverlay{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
.item:hover .itemOverlay{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes